# display array foreach record

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

Hi I have a table I am wanting to query but am a bit rusty and could do with some help.

So first of all, table structure:

```
SELECT
clientsites.ClientSitePk,
clientsites.ClientFk,
clientsites.SiteName,
clientsites.SiteType,
clientsites.FileNamePrefix,
clientsites.TempPostCode,
clientsites.TempPAF,
clientsites.ActualPAF,
concat_ws('\n', IF(LENGTH(pafaddresses.Line1),pafaddresses.Line1,NULL), IF(LENGTH(pafaddresses.Line2),pafaddresses.Line2,NULL), IF(LENGTH(pafaddresses.Line3),pafaddresses.Line3,NULL), IF(LENGTH(pafaddresses.Line4),pafaddresses.Line4,NULL), IF(LENGTH(pafaddresses.Line5),pafaddresses.Line5,NULL), IF(LENGTH(pafaddresses.PostTown),pafaddresses.PostTown,NULL), IF(LENGTH(pafaddresses.County),
pafaddresses.County,NULL), IF(LENGTH(pafaddresses.PostCode),pafaddresses.PostCode,NULL), IF(LENGTH(pafaddresses.CountryName),pafaddresses.CountryName,NULL)) AS AddressLabel,
pafaddresses.PostCode AS `Map`,
clientsites.Country,
clientsites.AddressLine1,
clientsites.AddressLine2,
clientsites.AddressLine3,
clientsites.AddressLine4,
clientsites.AddressLine5,
clientsites.PostTown,
clientsites.County,
clientsites.PostCode
FROM clientsites
INNER JOIN pafaddresses ON clientsites.ActualPAF = pafaddresses.id
```

What I am trying to do is to create a query that returns all the `clientsites.ClientSitePk` and `pafaddresses.PostCode` for each record where `clientsites.Country=1`, but I am struggling.

Here is what I have so far:

```
        //get client addresses in UK only
        $rstmp = CustomQuery("SELECT * FROM clientsites where Country=1");
        $datatmp = db_fetch_array($rstmp);

        foreach ($datatmp as $row)
        {
            echo $row["ClientSitePk"];
        }
```

Unfortunately it is not returning with any results, when in fact there are about 200 rows of data in that table that meet this criteria, could someone please tell me how to

a) correct this query and

b) include the joined table to get the `pafaddresses.PostCode` value too.

Comment: What you gave is a select query, not your structure. It is possible to suggest based on this query, but could you also add some data. At this point I think it has nothing to do with the query, so could you also post your php

Comment: output `var_dump($datatmp);`

Comment: http://prntscr.com/9amr6i